# windows with webdriver selenium python

Tags: python

how many window can we open with: `execute_script("window.open('','new window')").`
For example, when trying to execute this code :

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.maximize_window()
for i in range(4):
    driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.google.com','new window')")
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[i+1])
    time.sleep(4)
    os.system('pause')
```

i have this error (out of range):

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[i+1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: your window_handles call will try to call a value that's out the range of range(4). when it gets to the last iteration it will try to call i+1 which doesn't exist

Comment: even if we do it line by line:

Comment: jignasha, my question was clear: how many window can we open with execute_script(), because i can't open more than two windows. thanks :)

Comment: i rectify my comment, how many tabs can we open by winow. In my case, i can't open more than 2 tabs by window

Answer (score 0):

even if we do it line by line:

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.google.com','new window')")
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
time.sleep(4)
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.google.com','new window')")
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[2])
time.sleep(4)
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.google.com','new window')")
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[3])
time.sleep(4)
river.execute_script("window.open('https://www.google.com','new window')")
```

the same error message is displayed

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because you are trying to access a object that is not already created.

You need a sleep or check before the object exists.

Comment: index is from 0 to 3

Comment: the problem is i can't open more than 2 tabs by window

Comment: Dani Garcia, i have fixed the problem,  driver.execute_script(" window.open('//http','blank ') instead of driver.execute_script(" window.open('//http','new window '). thanks for your sharing :)